# Speaking of Which or Saying of Which

Tags: phrase-meaning

Googling "speaking of which", i got some results defining the meaning of the phrase. But googling "saying of which" there are no relevant results. However, in a movie clip (star wars I), i did hear the phrase "saying of which".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fchC0Dscm9I&t=10

Just wondering if this is a valid phrase or just something made up by the movie makers.

Answer (score 1):

The character in the movie does say "Saying of which" but it also says it in an accent which indicates that English is not its first language. Its own language may not have different verbs for *speak* and *say,* which might lead to confusion. Indeed, this sort of device in cinematic scriptwriting is a method of indicating the foreignness of the speaker — Hercule Poirot was famous for his "humbility".

It is a malapropism: the English "speaking of which" is a *fixed expression.*